# Change Symbology of no value in ArcGIS Online

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, arcade

I created web map in ArcGIS Online with point data. I will update one field of attribute which doesn't have any value on it (empty) with random number or text. I just want when I am putting any number or text or both of them for pop up the point change to different color without going to ArcGIS Online and change style and ungroup them to different value with different color?

I think I need to write expression but I am not familiar with arcade expression.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, this would require an Arcade expression. The particular function you're looking for is `IsEmpty()`. This function will output either `true` or `false`, depending on whether the field is empty. Combining that with a logical and operator will accomplish what you want.

To use it in reference to two layers, do the following:

1. Open up the symbology menu of your points layer, then select `New Expression` in the dropdown menu.

[image: new expression]

2. In the expression builder that pops up, write a statement like this.

   `IsEmpty($feature.field_1) && IsEmpty($feature.field_2)`
3. Make sure to select your new custom expression as the attribute to symbolize. You'll now have a simple two-color scheme that identifies points where both fields are empty/null.

Here's an example which uses this expression. Notice that the blue point has no value in either field. The red points have a value in either field, or both.

[image: boolean symbols with false popup][image: boolean symbol with true popup]